# How to Create Serial Number as per the last entry in mysql

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want two Create an automatic Serial Number as a reference Number what I am really looking for is :

once the serial number is generated it will not repeat again and choose next serial number as per the last generated serial number in SQL like If I Created the serial 20190926 then i don't want to generate this serial number again it will start from 20190927 automatically as its already generated also once the month ends the serial number will starts from 01 again like 201910001 I tried the given code but no success

```
$id = date('Ym').str_pad($n + 1, 3, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

it's giving me the current year and month but every time new form opened it started with 201909001 and I have to edit it again

thanks in advance

Comment: So are you fetching the `MAX()` serial id and comparing the first 6 digits against the current `Ym` before attempting to generate an appropriate new serial number?

Comment: no this variable create with following pattern: first 6 digits are current year and month and remaing 3 are just serial number which shows how many entries done during month

Comment: Yes, I follow that detail.  How can you reliably calculate `$n` without checking the date?

Comment: thats the issue thats why i need help

Comment: If you are interested in a sexy, pure-SQL solution, we might need to see some column names.  Otherwise, we can more simply recommend a php solution after the max seial number is returned from a query.

Answer (score 0):

To determine if you are dealing with the first entry of a given month, you will need to query your db table for the `MAX()` serial number -- lets refer to that value as php variable `$max`.

```
$Ym = date('Ym');
if (strpos($max, $Ym) === 0) {
    ++$max;
} else {
    $max = $Ym . '001';
}
```

Then use the new `$max` in your INSERT query.

...and of course, there is the very real concern of a "race condition" creating conflicting serial numbers.

Comment: @Detail what is the status of this quesion/page? Resolved or not resolved?  Do you need me to explain or adjust anything?